# Not able to load template in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

I am trying to load my template in html. But it give me some trouble in loading content of template in my div element. It gives me **Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'appendTo'**

temp.html is the file where div is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <title>HTML</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $.get('template.html', function(templates) {
                var template1 = $(templates).filter("tmplFeatures").html();
                $("#tmplFeatures").tmpl(template1).appendTo("carouseldata");
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="carouseldata" style="background-color:#FF0000; width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 50">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

template.html file containing template

```
<script id ="tmplFeatures" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <div id="mydata" style="overflow-x:hidden;width: 100%;height: 100%">
                        <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                            <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/lock.png" align="middle" />
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/thumb-comcast.gif" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><img id="image3" src="images/image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="images/image4.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><img src="images/image5.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><img src="images/image6.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><img src="images/image7.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><img src="images/image8.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><img src="images/image9.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><img src="images/image10.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
                                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: -85px;z-index: 60;background-color: #000000;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);width: 400;height:80px">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="200" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/divider.png" width="2" height="40" align="middle"/>
                                    <img src="images/cbs.png" width="100" height="70" align="middle"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: whatever `tmpl(template1)` is supposed to be/doing, obviously it has no `appendTo` method.

Comment: Do you think it is because I don't have #tmplFeatures in the current file where the appendTo is called.

Comment: if that was the case, the error would complaing about no `Object has no tmpl() method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a couple of issues here ...

First I think your template call is non syntactically correct:

```
$("#tmplFeatures").tmpl(template1).appendTo("carouseldata");
```

Should (according to the documentation) look like this:

```
$.tmpl( "tmplFeatures", template1).appendTo("carouseldata");
```

But I'm not sure that you can pass HTML (template1) as the 'data' parameter for the `.tmpl()` method:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

**UPDATE**

Looking more closely at your code above, it does not appear that you are passing any data to the `.tmpl()` call. It's not clear what the following line returns, but this should be the iterable data your template will be used to display.

```
var template1 = $(templates).filter("tmplFeatures").html();
```

And this looks like (possibly) another representation of the template.

Comment: Yes You are correct. The error goes away but it still does not load template on html page.

Comment: If I'm not mistatken `template1` returns HTML? I think this needs to be an `Array` or an `Object` (parsed JSON)

Comment: Ok Kevin, Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you are using this correctly. You might want to look over the documentation and re-approach the problem: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Comment: Yes I am not passing any data to template. My data is all hardcoded in template html at the moment.I do not need to pass data in that case.

Comment: Then you do not need to use `.tmpl()`. Simply store that HTML and append it when needed.